# How can I select same data from tables matching pattern

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to pull data from a database where the creator made a table for each of hundreds of samples. I need to pull two columns of data, `VardId` and `sanger`, from each table matching the pattern `pt\d+` (the letters `pt` followed by a string of numbers). Is there a nice one-liner I can use to get all the info?

Comment: Do you have easy access to a scripting language you can use to build a dynamic SQL statement (you're going to need one)?

Comment: A stored procedure is also possible to build dynamic SQL, but it can be uglier than just using Python or PHP or similar.

Comment: @Michael - Thanks for the edit. Newer to SO and needed the reminder.

Comment: Oh no problem. To format code inline, surround it in `\`backticks\``

Comment: I am a decently strong Perl user and can definitely code a solution. I am trying to strengthen my SQL though, and I would have thought MySQL had a simple way of doing this. Thanks for the help

Comment: The way to do it is to query the `information_schema.TABLES` table for table names matching your pattern, then you have to loop over them to build a giant `UNION` query to get the columns you needed (that's why this was an unfortunate schema design)

Comment: If someone is going to down vote, at least comment why. I definitely did plenty of googling prior to asking the question